# Common fixes for a mismatch in row count between Source and Sink databases when using Azure Data Factory Upsert Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've got a pipeline in ADF that has a lookup to grab me all the tables from a couple of schemas as well as key columns that I've personally defined for the tables. I then have a Copy Activity using Upsert. Now, whenever I do a row comparison between the Source database and the Sink database, I notice that there are a lot of tables where the row count is slightly off between the two Source and Sink tables. I'm not sure exactly how to trouble shoot why this is happening. The only thing I could think of is defining new key columns, but I feel they're accurate.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure exactly how to trouble shoot why this is happening.

This is odd and if the keys are defined correctly it should not happen . Having said that if I were you i would have tried to find the records/rows which are mismatched . To do that you can use Mapping dataflow and set the sink and source as source1 and sourc2 and then use the exists activity .

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm not sure I fully understand how this would work. It doesn't look like source2 is connected to anything. Could you explain why it wouldn't just be source > exists > sink? ```set the sink and source as source1 and sourc2``` < This also has me a little confused. Any elaboration would be greatly appreciated, new to data factory. That being said I will try and replicate this, if I can.